# Why are 150k or 200k jobs considered good when there are 300k+ births a month?

Tags: united-states, economy, demographics

It would seem that most people who are born will eventually enter the workforce. Maybe that entry is delayed due to college or enlistment or that very important backpacking trip through Europe, but it seems that most people born will eventually get hired somewhere.

So when you hear that the economy increased by fewer than 200k jobs, but over 300k people entered the labor pool, doesn't that really mean 100k more unemployed people? It doesn't seem like any figure smaller than 300k jobs is even breaking even against population growth. What am I missing here?

Comment: People die. It's true.

Comment: I don't really understand how this question got so many upvotes when it is failing to take into account the obvious factor of the rate at which people leave the labor force.  This is not a good question.  At all.

Comment: @John The question entered HNQ and visitors can upvote but not downvote.

Comment: Lots of people don't work... students, stay at home moms (and dads), retirees, the disabled, homeless, people on extended leave (just because they have the means to do so), military (I don't think that is in your jobs numbers), kids in their 20's and even 30's that live with their parents and don't want to work, etc.

Comment: @RobertHanson Don't forget the dead. They're by far the most important bulk of workforce lost :P

Answer (score 68):

The obvious answer is that people get older and (presumably, hopefully) retire from the workforce.

If your country's demographic is otherwise more or less stable, it means that by the time those 300,000 people age up to enter the work force, a similar number of people retire *from* the work force and hopefully live on their pension plan.

Comment: +1, though we've also got an aging population.  [Figure 1](https://www.prb.org/us-fertility/) shows US population growth was largest  ~1950 and 1965, which corresponds to folks between the ages of 55 and 70

Comment: Or more analogously to the "300k births" number, there are also 230k deaths per month. So anything above about 70k new jobs per month is a surplus. (I know this is a vast oversimplification)

Comment: See Business Insider that did the "calculus" to arrive at an answer of how many jobs need be created to maintain balanced population/jobs. Their answer 203,000  per month.  [ https://www.businessinsider.com/the-job-market-is-getting-worse-because-of-population-growth-2016-8 ]

Answer (score 23):

In addition to the other answers, it should be noted that jobs don't just exist independent of people. The only reason jobs exist is that people create the need for jobs, so more people means more jobs.

Comment: A small correction.  People create the need for products and services, and that need creates jobs.  There are times when society creates jobs merely because jobs are needed, but that is, at best, a temporary fix.  Unless the work product is of value, ultimately the job is just a tranfer payment in disguise.

Comment: But if jobs are automated away, there is LESS need for jobs. Driving long distance trucks (3.5M) and taxis (+Uber and Lyft: 1M) might be 90% automated in a decade. All those millions of people doing it now will need to find new skills to be paid for (to be able to pay other people).

Comment: Yeah, this is only true in a world where productivity per worker is constant. The need for additional production can _either_ be accomplished by having more jobs at the same productivity _or_ the same number of jobs (or fewer!) at an increased productivity. This is, in fact, what we might see as automation really gets going - the increase in productivity per worker may be high enough that the number of available jobs will decrease despite the continual growth in needed production. It makes you wonder how our current system of basically requiring employment will react.

Comment: One way to fix this is to have wages tied to productivity, so that the few people who have jobs in production can afford to pay people to do things for them and expand the service economy to make up for the gap. Unfortunately, at least in the US, productivity and wages have not been related since around 1973 (see e.g. https://www.epi.org/productivity-pay-gap/). Real wages have remained roughly constant as productivity continues to grow.

Comment: On obsolescence of work, I can add a made-up quote of a working man circa 1890: ``Cars will make hundreds of thousands of horse carriage drivers jobless!``and telephone operators 30 years later, and human computers 30 years later, and so on. There will always be new more advanced jobs that follow major changes.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen The word _always_ is a very strong word. Earlier technological advancements either substituted a few skilled jobs with many unskilled jobs (e.g. the advent of mass production replacing artisans), which meant a net creation of jobs, or substituted a set of unskilled jobs with another set of unskilled jobs (e.g. replacing horse carriage manufacture and driving with car manufacture and driving), which meant that adaptation was quick as little retraining was needed. Currently, unskilled jobs are being replaced by skilled jobs (e.g. manufacture -> software development).

Comment: @JuhaUntinen This wouldn't be a problem if substantial retraining programs were in place to ensure similar mobility as in the past, but those don't really exist to any meaningful extent in the US at present. So where are all of the unskilled workers going to go? Saying that the workforce will always adapt on its own to technological advances because it has done so in the past is like saying that you don't need to wear a seatbelt because you've never been in a car crash. Things might just be different this time, and taking precautions is not unreasonable.

Comment: @probably_someone Sure, but if you believed that, you would support precautions that actually help. But does it really feel to you that people are more capable of dealing with changes than in the past? The only thing that even _pretends_ to deal with the problem is the approach of "basic income" and silly ideas like that. In any case, it's not about "it was always like this, so why would that change?". It's that to expect it to change, you would need to also expect those people aren't able to give enough value to make a living _despite_ the products of their work becoming ever cheaper.

Comment: @probably_someone You're essentially saying that at some point in the future, unskilled labour will have so little value that you couldn't even support your own life. But humans have survived completely isolated; a single human can support himself even without tools or help (_barely_). Cooperation with other humans makes that easier. Real living costs are going down over time, even for unskilled workers; especially if you remove taxes, inflation etc. While there are people who are a lot better off than unskilled workers, those unskilled workers still earn much more than previous generations.

Answer (score 14):

"300k people entered the labor pool" and "300k+ births a month" are very different things.

You can get to 300k new people in labor pool, if you have 150k people reaching employment age, and 150k of previously long-term unemployed people (excluded from the labor pool by labor statistics bureau) started looking for a job (because they decided such with low unemployment, they have chance to get the job even if they could not get it before).

And to get to 150k people reaching employment age you need more that 150k births, 20 years earlier.

We have no idea how many jobs will be available 20 years from now for people born now. It could be singularity and robots will do all the work. Or climate collapse could start WW3.

And then there is immigration, legal and illegal.

Comment: thanks for adding numbers: other answers miss that part.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to other answers. (+1 to [Kloddant](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/40284/5994)).

Note newborns will only enter the labor market after 20 years or more. The economy is supposed to grow (even when the population is stable) a lot in that time frame, so by the time anybody born today ends college the new jobs increase ratios is supposed to be a lot higher than today.
Of course, no one can give us a real number of new jobs created for 2039. But we hope it will be more than 300k.

Comment: yes, but with automation the economy (=GDP) can grow while jobs shrink at the same time.

Comment: But the people entering the job market now correspond to births 20ish years ago, and he's assuming the birth rate was roughly comparable then.

Comment: @Fizz There are lots of things to consider. Someone talked about immigration, for example, but that is peanuts compared to job migration (when you close a facility in Europe to reopen another in Asia). Analysts try to extrapolate all those graphs and that's why you cannot correlate today birth rate with today jobs increase rate. In fact, if jobs increase rate was as big as birth rate that can mean you really need immigrants and automation badly.

Comment: That might happen even without automation; South Africa is an example https://www.economist.com/special-report/2010/06/03/jobless-growth

Comment: Correction: we _hope_ newborns will only enter the labour market after 20 years or more.

Answer (score 2):

> "On average, 205,300 jobs need to be created every month just to keep up with population growth"

per [Business Insider Aug 2016](https://www.businessinsider.com/the-job-market-is-getting-worse-because-of-population-growth-2016-8).

Their article appears to be an analysis of this issue, however I will leave it to the reader to debate the accuracy and/or validity of the conclusion.  If the analysis was valid in 2016, I would think that it is equally valid 2.5 years later.

Answer (score -1):

Other posters noted that you need to subtract the number of people who age out of the labor force from the number of people who reach the adulthood each year.  In a thriving society, both numbers are substantially less then the number of births.

In a thriving society, a large fraction of the working age population does not work for monetary pay.  They have better things to do:  Homemaking, raising children well, gardening, volunteer work.

If a society manages to have 90 % of its working age men working, and 30 % of its working age women working, and does not have net immigration/emigration of working age adults, then the rate of creating net new jobs should average about 60 % of the rate of net new working age adults.

Comment: A society with an excess of births is not thriving, it is on the road to suffering from overpopulation, if not actually there yet.  Also, it is observed that in economically healthy societies, most people do not consider homemaking, child rearing, and so forth to be better things to do.

Answer (score -2):

Quick answer. Money is produced by private and corporate bank loans. With a fixed base money supply (because bond rates have been flat for 40 years now) this means debt can not be repaid because it amounts to more money then there exists. So there things allow this to continue, new loans but this grows the interest leading to the other two. Alternatively the loans can default, or the banks can essentially give money back.

The give back is why we don't need 100% employment. Most middle class can live off investment and pensions. With enough principle it is trivial matter of funding.

This is in contrast to prior where you got the give back from a know, standard source, gov bonds. Reliable, riskless, standard insertion of new currency. Today bond rates have been flat and non competitive. With growing world economy private and corporate banks use debt to create new money and give interest back through literally any way you can think of. Insanely well paying do nothing jobs, artificial investment growth, or sometimes not at all, bankruptcy.